# Is there a way to make React Native custom components without UI?

Tags: react-native, custom-component

I am writing a custom component for a Windows 8.1 tablet application our team are mostly developing in React Native.

I've realised that some of the custom code we need doesn't naturally belong to any specific UI element. For example, we want a button to trigger the native Camera UI dialog (as in [this CameraUICapture element sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CameraCaptureUI-Sample-845a53ac)). However, there's no reason this would necessarily be triggered from a button. It could be a callback from something else, it could be a click event on an image. I don't want to lock the function calls to a specific UI piece.

All the tutorials and demos I have managed to find so far for React Custom Components are explicitly for UI pieces, and require implementing a React View manager subclass to interact with React when the piece is loaded. Is this the only way to write native code accessible from a React page? Do I need at least a dummy UI element even to hook into functional code in the native layer, or is there another way?

Comment: You might want something like mixin or a free function. Also this [read](https://reactjs.org/blog/2016/07/13/mixins-considered-harmful.html) might be of interest.

Comment: This makes sense from the JS end but I would need a clearer idea how to implement this on the C# end. Nice Dijkstra reference on the mixin post though :)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the phrase I'm yearning for is "Native **Modules**".

iOS:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html

Android:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html

Windows:
https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows/blob/master/docs/NativeModulesWindows.md